# How can I alter the text height and width on a text?

Tags: width, amsart, text, height

I need to fit a six page document into five pages and would like to increase the text height and perhaps the text width a bit.  I used \textheight and \textwidth but to no avail.  Can you help me please?  Here is the code: I am leaving even the useless in case something might be the culprit.  Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{times}

\linespread{0.5} %interlinea: 1 e 1/2
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\baselineskip 10pt
\oddsidemargin 0pt
\evensidemargin 0pt
%\topmargin -40pt
\headheight 50pt
\headsep 10pt
\footskip 32pt
\textheight 250mm
\textwidth 190mm


\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb,amscd}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx, epsfig, psfrag}
\usepackage{pb-diagram}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wasysym, auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{epstopdf,yfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\bf CURRICULUM VITAE}
\end{center}

Here it goes the text (it should be long to see whether it works)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `geometry` package instead of accessing all these low-level variables.

Comment: Well, thank you for the suggestion. Actually I don't need most of them, I left only a \usepackage{text comp, lmodern} and \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}.  But it does not change my question.

Comment: near the end of the file `amsart.cls` there is a definition for the command `\calclayout`.  the dimensions are calculated using this mechanism, and there's a fair amount of arithmetic involved, but i think it's pretty clear; at least the names of the components are mostly familiar.  i don't have a copy handy, so i can't give details.  but if you follow the logical flow, it works quite well.  i've added the tag `[amsart]` because this is very specific to that class.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like beyond my immediate capabilities...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this preamble:

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{0.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[textheight=25 cm, textwidth=19cm, headheight=50pt, headsep=10pt, footskip=32pt]{geometry}
```

Note some of the packages  you load  are obsolete (`times`, `epsfig`). `times` doesn't have support for maths ans should be replaced with `newtxtext,newtxmath`. As to `epsfig`, all its functionalities are available with `graphicx`. Also, it's better to load `setspace` and write `\setstretch{0.5}` rather than coding `\linespread{0.5}`. Last, `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the tips about the packages.  As for the rest, I used the preamble you suggested, but now the text is all shifted up (a bit too much) leaving a lot of space on the bottom.  How do I change this?

Comment: Sorry, it worked!  There were lots of \def and \newcommand and, embedded into these, there were other spurious stretching factors that I could correct.  Thanks a lot!